# how to read the values from completablefuture after it is returned from the method

Tags: java

```
List<CompletableFuture<GreetHolder>> completableFutures = langList.stream()
                                                                  .map(lang -> getGreeting(lang))
                                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]));

CompletableFuture<List<GreetHolder>> allCompletableFuture = allFutures.thenApply(future -> {
    return completableFutures.stream().map(completableFuture -> completableFuture.join()).collect(Collectors.toList());
});

CompletableFuture completableFuture = allCompletableFuture.thenApply(greets -> {
    return greets.stream().map(GreetHolder::getGreet).collect(Collectors.toList());
});

completableFuture.get();
```

```
private CompletableFuture<GreetHolder> getGreeting (String lang){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            logger.info("Task execution started.");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            logger.info("Task execution stopped.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new GreetHolder(getGreet(lang));
        }, pool);
    }
}
```

I want to read the List of greeting values returned from either from `allCompletableFuture` or `completableFutureCompleted`. I am not sure how to read the values returned by `getGreeting` method and output the list to the screen. Please feel free to modify the code if needed in the last step.

Answer (score 0):

Your greetings are returned by `completableFuture.get();` but you aren't capturing them in your example.

Assuming "getGreet" returns a string, does this work?

```
List<String> greetings = completableFuture.get();
```

Comment: you want me to call get() replacing join call?

Comment: I missed the join, no that should work also. In your example you aren't storing the responses, updated my answer with another guess.